# Progressive images with HTML

Tags: html, image

I've recently come across a situation to work with progressive images. My understanding is, image has to be stored as progressive and browsers will do the loading job.

To prove this, I've created an image as progressive image (with 3 parses and 5 parses) and used it in a sample HTML file with <img> tag. I've uploaded the HTML and image the server. And I don't see any progressive loading.

Is there anything we should do to enable it? As I said, I thought browser will do the loading part automatically.

<<Update>>
Here the example HTML - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2456662/Progressive/progressive-demo.html
First two images are exported as progressive images with 3 parses and 5 parses respectivey. Thrid image is the base line image.

When I access the HTML, all 3 are downloaded like base line (regular model). Progressive should load the entire picture in the first shot followed by other pixels - right?

Comment: What image format have you used? Please share the HTML code and image with us if you can. With the information we have now, I'd guess that your connection is simply so fast that you don't notice the image is loaded progressively.

Comment: What do you mean with "progessive image"?

Comment: Hi Ulrich - I've now updated my question with HTML link. Please check and get back, thanks